# Magento 2: How can write jquery in html file?

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs

I try it but not working with html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: On which html file you want?

Comment: i want write script on my custom html file.

Comment: Where are you calling it? What is the logic of that html file?

Comment: i call it in checkout_index_index

Comment: what is your error? "not working" is no sufficient information

Comment: what error you are getting?Try using UI component method(Knockout js)

Comment: i don't know. i just want write it for alert in html file so nothing, no error it just not working

Comment: give file path  in which are you adding script

Comment: Why do u call html , You can use phtml file in layout instead of html

Comment: If you need html, Then you should have Ui component without that you can't add script in html

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
</script>
```

If you give it the alias $ you also have to use this alias

Comment: I tried but it not working :(

Comment: you have to deploy content after change in html file

Comment: @KetanBorada wrong! if you configured your system correct you do not have to deploy. symlinks is the key

Comment: how you sure he allow symlinks?he tried your solu.but not works?